# Looking to use ARRAYFORMULA to increment-count adjacent rows containing either TRUE or FALSE

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, counting

I have a dynamic table in Google Sheets that has, among other irrelevant columns, column B that has done various calculations and resulted in either TRUE or FALSE for each row in B4:B500 (the first three rows are headers and summaries).

What I would like is to be able to calculate in another column (C would be good!) how many TRUEs there have been so far (top down) in the current *streak* and, when B changes to FALSE, do the same thing, resetting back to 1 at each change in B's value.

Here is a link to example of my data (sorry, rep<10 so can't just post the image):
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwcDU.jpg)

Since the actual data is a lot more than ~20 rows and will be updated at least once per day for the foreseeable future, I'd prefer to use ARRAYFORMULA to calculate C rather than having to drag formulae down. Additionally, unless the scripting is extraordinarily simplified, I have a very strong preference for formulae rather than scripts.

If I wanted all of the TRUEs or all of the FALSEs (or even all within a pre-determined range), I could do that already; it's the dynamic nature of the problem that is stumping me.

advTHANKSance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one to try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B2:B="",,row(B2:B)-
if(B2:B,
iferror(vlookup(row(B2:B),if(not(B2:B),row(B2:B)),1),1),
iferror(vlookup(row(B2:B),if(B2:B,row(B2:B)),1),1))))
```

[image]

A more general expression for the iferror value if you want to start in row 4 etc:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B4:B="",,row(B4:B)-
if(B4:B,
iferror(vlookup(row(B4:B),if(not(B4:B),row(B4:B)),1),min(row(B4:B))-1),
iferror(vlookup(row(B4:B),if(B4:B,row(B4:B)),1),min(row(B4:B))-1))))
```

or for your specific requirements:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B4:B="",,row(B4:B)-
if(B4:B,
iferror(vlookup(row(B4:B),if(not(B4:B),row(B4:B)),1),3),
iferror(vlookup(row(B4:B),if(B4:B,row(B4:B)),1),3))))
```

Comment: Thank you SO VERY MUCH for this. It not only does the job I asked for, but manages to not be limited by my (dumb) requirement of B4:B500. Best of all, I already understand all of it.

Comment: That's good to hear - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear C4:C500, then place the following in cell C4:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B4:B500="",, ROW(B4:B500) - VLOOKUP(ROW(B4:B500), FILTER(ROW(B4:B500), B4:B500<>"", B4:B500<>B3:B499), 1, TRUE) + 1))`

The `FILTER` creates a list of all row numbers corresponding with non-null cells from B4:B where the current cell doesn't have the same value as the previous cell. This list will contain only the rows that "restart" a new value.

`VLOOKUP` with a final parameter of `TRUE` will lookup every row number corresponding with B4:B500 within that `FILTER`ed short list above and "fall back" to the nearest value. So if the `FILTER`ed list starts `4, 8, 9...` then row 5 will return `4`, row 6 will return `4`, etc. Subtracting that most recent fall-back row number from every actual row number will product the count from the last change.

We add `+1` because the count at each change point starts at 1 not at 0. For instance, for row 4, we'd get 4 (current row) - 4 (fall back value) = 0; but we want row 4 to start the count at 1, hence the `+1` to each value.

Comment: simplier than mine!

Comment: This one does absolutely everything I asked for -- but the solution I picked gets rid of the artificial limitation that I specified in the original requirements. Thank you!

Comment: We can, of course, only write solutions around the information provided. Modifying this formula to run the full length of the column is possible. But it seems you have a working solution already, so all is well.

Answer (score 0):

With 2 columns ... (without specifying the end of the column)

in C2

```
=arrayformula(B4:B&(SUMIF(ROW(B4:B),"<="&ROW(B4:B),C4:C)))
```

in D2

```
=arrayformula((row(B4:B)<=transpose(row(B4:B)))*((B4:B&(SUMIF(ROW(B4:B),"<="&ROW(B4:B),C4:C)))=TRANSPOSE((B4:B&(SUMIF(ROW(B4:B),"<="&ROW(B4:B),C4:C))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your work. It's better than the 3-column solution I had been working towards (for one thing, it actually works!), but others were more streamlined.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: A much more concise formula which uses a similar logic:

`=index(if(B4:B="",,len(RegexReplace(left(join(,left(B4:B)),row(B4:B)-3),".*"&if(B4:B,"F","T"),))))`

Here's a different approach with Regex.

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(len(RegexExtract(RegexReplace(RegexReplace(join(,B4:B500),"RUE|ALSE",),"^(.{"&sequence(counta(B4:B500))&"})","$1~"),"(.*)~"))-len(RegexExtract(RegexReplace(RegexReplace(join(,B4:B500),"RUE|ALSE",),"^(.{"&sequence(counta(B4:B500))&"})","$1~"),"(.*"&if(RegexExtract(RegexReplace(RegexReplace(join(,B4:B500),"RUE|ALSE",),"^(.{"&sequence(counta(B4:B500))&"})","$1~"),"(.)~")="T","F","T")&").+~")),sequence(999)))`

[image]

It's not the best solution both in terms of length and versatility as it's only designed to work with this specific input (TRUE/FALSE) but it was an interesting problem so I wanted to give it a try.

Comment: Great job and thank you for both potential solutions. I chose another because I already fully understood the formula, not because it was any better than this.